# VB Mouse click in background running process

Tags: vb.net, click, mouse

I’m making an VB application which runs another process (windowed game). My app acts as a macro to that game.

I’m struggling to get mouse click working, although my code to send keys in the background works excellent (can provide if needed).

I mean the program to click into specific location within the process in the background, that means I could be browsing internet or playing another game when that mouse click takes action.

I'm getting an error message: Specified cast is not valid.

Error is on InputPressRightMouse Sub where:

PostMessage(Handle, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 1, coord)

```
Private Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN As System.UInt32 = &H204
Private Const WM_RBUTTONUP As System.UInt32 = &H205

Dim coord = MakeDWord(-220, 85)

Private Function MakeDWord(ByVal LoWord As Integer, ByVal HiWord As Integer) As Long
    MakeDWord = (HiWord * &H10000) Or (LoWord And &HFFFF&)
End Function

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function PostMessage(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal Msg As System.UInt32, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal wParam As System.IntPtr, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.In()> ByVal lParam As System.UIntPtr) As System.Boolean
End Function

Public Sub InputPressKey(ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, CType(Key, System.IntPtr), CType(WM_KEYDOWNLPARAM, System.UIntPtr))
End Sub
Public Sub InputReleaseKey(ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_KEYUP, CType(Key, System.IntPtr), CType(WM_KEYUPLPARAM, System.UIntPtr))
End Sub

Public Sub InputPressRightMouse(ByVal Handle As System.IntPtr, ByVal Mouse As System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons)
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 1, coord)
End Sub
```

And code to perform mouse click:

```
    InputPressRightMouse(Process.MainWindowHandle, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
```

Code to send key (which works)

```
InputPressKey(Process.MainWindowHandle, System.Windows.Forms.Keys.V)
```

Can somebody help with what I did wrong here?

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Also, you appear to have a superfluous ampersand in your `MakeDWord()` method: `(LoWord And &HFFFF&)` - it should just be: `(LoWord And &HFFFF)`.

Comment: `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` is sent to the Windows that has the mouse capture, or to the Window beneath the cursor. You have `Option.Strict` OFF.

Comment: I get the error on line: 
PostMessage(Handle, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, &H2, coord)

Comment: Can somebody help?

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error message or is that it? It could caused by what you pass to the `(U)IntPtr` parameters. You ought to always use the correct type, turning on `Option Strict` is a good thing to do. Try: `PostMessage(Handle, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, New IntPtr(&H2), New UIntPtr(CType(coord, ULong)))`